# Program shuts off without anything C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace Zadacha
{
    class Zadacha
    {
        static int Read(int x, int y)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Vuvedete minimalna velichina");
            string MinValue = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Vuvedete maximalna velichina");
            string MaxValue = Console.ReadLine();
            int.TryParse(MinValue, out x);
            int.TryParse(MaxValue, out y);
            int value = rnd.Next(x, y);
            Console.WriteLine("Proizvodnoto chislo e: " + value);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            return value;
        }
        static void Main()
        {

        }   
    }
}
```

This is my code, program just starts and shutdowns after a second with no text in the console app. Everything seems fine and i do not know what is wrong. It is a uni task.

Comment: That `static void Main(){}` doesn't do anything in the first place. No wonder it terminates immediatelly

Comment: Add some calls to your Main()

Comment: In C# the program starts in `static void Main()`

Comment: You have to add to the `Main ` the call of read function `Console.ReadLine(Read(5, 5))`

Comment: Besides the empty `Main()` there is a potential problem. You call `bool int.TryParse()` but you never check if the parsing was OK (that function returns true if it could parse).

Comment: Every new programmer start with Hello world examples...and it is the answer for your question - start from beggining. Check [Hello World example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/hello-world-your-first-program)

Comment: I updated your code to  be like this:https://onlinegdb.com/SJO_abEJ4

Answer (score 3):

You don't do anything in your Main method - you need to call your `Read(x,y)` method at least, and/or `Console.ReadLine();` in order for something to happen.

For example

```
static void Main()
{
   Read(1,2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feel so stupid right now, not using my main().... <3

Comment: @StiviKM no worries, sometimes we need a bit of rubber ducky-ing. Make sure to mark the answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve? Console apps start from `Main()` so you'll have to put something in there for the program to work. I guess you don't actually want to feed `Read()` two `int` you want to get the users input?

```
using System;

namespace Zadacha
{
    class Zadacha
    {
        static int Read()
        {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Vuvedete minimalna velichina");
            string MinValue = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Vuvedete maximalna velichina");
            string MaxValue = Console.ReadLine();
            int.TryParse(MinValue, out x);
            int.TryParse(MaxValue, out y);
            int value = rnd.Next(x, y);
            Console.WriteLine("Proizvodnoto chislo e: " + value);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            return value;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Read();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you modify `Read`'s signature?

Comment: @Adelin it makes no sense proving a argument and overriding its value a few lines later

Comment: Because OP want's to get the values from the user

Comment: @bradbury9 yeah but the change shouldn't be imposed with no explanation. If OP knew about that (which this post expects since it has no explanation), they would've changed it themselves.

Comment: Either OP knew about that but got the assignment wrong (just a typo) or did not in which case the OP would have learnt from the correction. Do note it is a university/high school task, so correcting the code seems fine to me.